# how to to define a function make_ 3 rd _form() which given a verb in infinitive form returns its third person singular form?

Tags: string, forms, python-2.7, infinite

I need to to define a function make_3rd_form() which given a verb in infinitive form returns its third person singular form.

The third person singular verb form in English is distinguished by the suffix-s, which is added to the stem of the infinitive form: run-> runs.

these are the rules:
If the verb ends in y, remove it and add ies

If the verb ends in o, ch, s, sh, x or z, add es

By default just add s.

I think that string method ends with() is the way.

I am new to python so any type of idea would be helpful.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try posting some code first, so we can see what direction you're going

Comment: What you are asking is an algorithm. This is not the place for this kind of question.

Comment: This is a programming question @VictorSchröder . I will post what I got as soon as I got something to post. I am still trying to figure out ways to do it.

Comment: @user3179932, no, it is not. This is a request for people write the programm for you, what is definitly not the subject of this community. If you'd written a piece of code and some function didn't worked, it's ok to ask. But request people to do the whole thing? Nop. This is against even to your own learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_3rd_form():
    word = raw_input('Please enter a word: ')
    if word[len(word)-1] == 'o' or word[len(word)-1] == 's' or word[len(word)-1] == 'x' or word[len(word)-1] == 'z':
        word = word + 'es'
        print word
    elif word[len(word)-2] == 'c' and word[len(word)-1] == 'h':
        word = word + 'es'
        print word
    elif word[len(word)-2] == 's' and word[len(word)-1] == 'h':
        word = word + 'es'
        print word
    elif word[len(word)-1] == 'y':
        word = word[:-1]
        word = word + 'ies'
        print word
    else:
        word = word + 's'
        print word

make_3rd_form()
```

Is this what you were thinking of? I hope so! However, if one of the requirements was to use with(), sorry, because clearly I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_3rd_form(verb):
    es = ('o', 'ch', 's', 'sh', 'x', 'z')
    if verb.endswith('y'):
        return re.sub('y$', 'ies', verb)
    elif verb.endswith(es):
        return verb + 'es'
    else:
        return verb + 's'
```